# Why is the original code section of the elf file not running?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, elf, packer

I am working on an elf packer. In this program, I read an elf file, then I add a section to it. And I set the entry point to that section and after that I jump to the original section of the executable code of file elf.And also the program headers has been updated.
The issue is that the executable code of the added section is executed and then jumps to the original executable section, but this section is not executed.
Currently, I am working on the 64-bit elf file part, and the other parts are comments. Below I have put different parts of the code.
I use Ubuntu and GCC and NASM assembler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include "addSection.hpp"

inline bool isFileExists(const std::string &name)
{
    std::ifstream f(name.c_str());
    return f.good();
}

#define EI_NIDENT 16

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];
    uint16_t e_type;
    uint16_t e_machine;
    uint32_t e_version;
    uint32_t e_entry;
    uint32_t e_phoff;
    uint32_t e_shoff;
    uint32_t e_flags;
    uint16_t e_ehsize;
    uint16_t e_phentsize;
    uint16_t e_phnum;
    uint16_t e_shentsize;
    uint16_t e_shnum;
    uint16_t e_shstrndx;
} ElfN_Ehdr;

void PrintHeader(Elf32_Ehdr &h);
void PrintHeader(Elf64_Ehdr &h);
void PrintPHVec32(std::vector<Elf32_Phdr> &PHs32);
void PrintPHVec64(std::vector<Elf64_Phdr> &PHs64);

void PrintPHStr();
void PrintSHStr();
void PrintRETab();
void PrintSMTab();

void clear_screen()
{
    std::cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    clear_screen();

    // std::cout << "\033[1;36m" << SHN_ABS  << "\t" << SHN_COMMON << std::endl;
    std::string pathFile{""};
    std::string sectionName{".text2"};
    std::string pathBin{"/home/zch/C++/Packer/MyPacker OK/rappers_delight.bin"};
    sectionName.reserve(100);
    std::string secTest;
    // Using a breakpoint as injected code
    // secTest.push_back(0x90);
    // secTest.push_back(0xcc);
    // secTest.push_back(0x90);
    // secTest.push_back(0x90);

    std::ifstream in(pathBin);
    if (in)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << in.rdbuf(); // reading data
        secTest = ss.str();
    }

    std::cout << "\033[1;32mEnter the Path file: \033[0m" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex;

    std::getline(std::cin, pathFile);

    if (isFileExists(pathFile))
    {
        ElfN_Ehdr header;
        char answer;
        std::ifstream input(pathFile, std::ios::binary);

        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});

        std::cout << "Add Section? " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> answer;

        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            addSection(sectionName, secTest, buffer);
        }

        sectionName.clear();

        memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));

        uint64_t offset = 0;
        uint32_t symNum = 0;

        if (header.e_ident[4] == 1)
        {
            Elf32_Ehdr header;
            memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));

            PrintHeader(header);

            std::vector<Elf32_Phdr> PHs32(header.e_phnum);
            std::vector<Elf32_Shdr> SHs32(header.e_shnum);
            offset = header.e_phoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_phnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&PHs32[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_phentsize);
                offset += header.e_phentsize;
            }

            PrintPHVec32(PHs32);

            offset = header.e_shoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_shnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&SHs32[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_shentsize);
                offset += header.e_shentsize;
            }
            offset = SHs32[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset;

            std::cout << "SHs32[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset " << SHs32[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset << std::endl;

            PrintSHStr();
            for (auto &e : SHs32)
            {
                sectionName.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    // std::cout << i << " e.sh_name " << e.sh_name << std::endl;
                    if (buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i] != '\0')
                    {
                        sectionName.push_back(buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                std::cout << sectionName << " ";
                std::cout << e.sh_name << "\t\t" << e.sh_type << "\t" << e.sh_flags << "\t" << e.sh_addr << "\t" << e.sh_offset << "\t" << e.sh_size << "\t" << e.sh_link << "\t" << e.sh_info << "\t" << e.sh_addralign << "\t\t" << e.sh_entsize << std::endl;
                std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Elf64_Ehdr header;
            memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));
            PrintHeader(header);

            std::vector<Elf64_Phdr> PHs64(header.e_phnum);
            std::vector<Elf64_Shdr> SHs64(header.e_shnum);
            offset = header.e_phoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_phnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&PHs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_phentsize);
                offset += header.e_phentsize;
            }

            PrintPHVec64(PHs64);

            offset = header.e_shoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_shnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&SHs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_shentsize);
                offset += header.e_shentsize;
            }

            uint32_t symTaOffset = 0;
            uint32_t strTaOffset = 0;
            uint32_t initArrTaOffset = 0;
            uint32_t gotTaOffset = 0;
            uint32_t gTabOffset = 0;
            uint32_t gTabSize = 0;

            PrintSHStr();
            offset = SHs64[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset;
            for (auto &e : SHs64)
            {
                sectionName.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i] != '\0')
                    {
                        sectionName.push_back(buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (sectionName == ".symtab")
                {
                    symTaOffset = e.sh_offset;
                    symNum = e.sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym);
                }
                if (sectionName == ".strtab")
                {
                    strTaOffset = e.sh_offset;
                }

                if (sectionName == ".init_array")
                {
                    initArrTaOffset = e.sh_offset;
                }

                if(sectionName == ".got")
                {
                    gTabOffset = e.sh_offset;
                    gTabSize = e.sh_size;

                }

                if (sectionName == ".plt.got")
                {
                    gotTaOffset = e.sh_offset;
                }

                std::cout << sectionName << " ";
                std::cout << e.sh_name << "\t\t" << e.sh_type << "\t" << e.sh_flags << "\t" << e.sh_addr << "\t" << std::hex << e.sh_offset << "\t" << e.sh_size << "\t" << e.sh_link << "\t" << e.sh_info << "\t" << e.sh_addralign << "\t\t" << e.sh_entsize << std::endl;
                std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            }

            offset = symTaOffset;

            std::vector<Elf64_Sym> SMs64(symNum);
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < symNum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&SMs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, sizeof(Elf64_Sym));
                offset += sizeof(Elf64_Sym);
            }

            PrintSMTab();
            std::cout << "info\t\t"
                      << "name\t\t"
                      << "other\t\t"
                      << "shndx\t\t"
                      << "size\t\t"
                      << "value\t\t" << std::endl;

            offset = strTaOffset;
            uint32_t count = 1;

            for (auto &e : SMs64)
            {
                sectionName.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (buffer[offset + e.st_name + i] != '\0')
                    {
                        sectionName.push_back(buffer[offset + e.st_name + i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                std::cout << std::dec << count++ << " >>\t" << static_cast<uint32_t>(e.st_info) << std::hex << "\t\t" << e.st_name << "\t\t" << static_cast<uint32_t>(e.st_other) << "\t\t" << e.st_shndx << std::hex << "\t\t" << e.st_size << "\t\t" << e.st_value << "\t\t";

                std::cout << "\t" << sectionName << std::endl;
                std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            }

            PrintRETab();

            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < SHs64.size(); i++)
            {
                if (SHs64[i].sh_type == 4)
                {
                    uint32_t size = SHs64[i].sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Rela);

                    std::vector<Elf64_Rela> REs64(size);
                    offset = SHs64[i].sh_offset;

                    for (uint32_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
                    {
                        memcpy(&REs64[j], buffer.data() + offset, sizeof(Elf32_Rela));
                        std::cout << "offset \t\t0x" << std::hex << REs64[j].r_offset << "\tinfo\t" << REs64[j].r_info << "\taddend\t" << REs64[j].r_addend << std::endl;
                        offset += sizeof(Elf64_Rela);
                    }

                    std::cout << "=============================================================================================" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            
            offset = gTabOffset;
            uint32_t got_size = gTabSize / 8;
            uint64_t addr = 0;

            for(uint32_t i = 0; i < got_size; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&addr, buffer.data()+ offset, 8);
                offset += 8;
                std::cout << "GOT Entry: " <<  std::dec <<  i << " 0x" << std::hex << addr << std::endl;
            }

            


        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Does Not Exist." << std::endl;
    }
}

void PrintHeader(Elf32_Ehdr &h)
{
    std::cout << "Magic: ";
    for (auto e : h.e_ident)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if (h.e_ident[4] == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "32 Bit " << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "64 Bit" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Type:\t\t" << h.e_type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "machine:\t\t" << h.e_machine << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Version:\t\t" << h.e_version << std::endl;
    std::cout << "entry:\t\t" << h.e_entry << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phoff:\t\t" << h.e_phoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shoff:\t\t" << h.e_shoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "flags:\t\t" << h.e_flags << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ehsize:\t\t" << h.e_ehsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phentsize:\t\t" << h.e_phentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phnum:\t\t" << h.e_phnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shentsize:\t\t" << h.e_shentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shnum:\t\t" << h.e_shnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shstrndx:\t\t" << h.e_shstrndx << std::endl;
}

void PrintHeader(Elf64_Ehdr &h)
{
    std::cout << "Magic: ";
    for (auto e : h.e_ident)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if (h.e_ident[4] == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "32 Bit " << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "64 Bit" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Type:\t\t" << h.e_type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "machine:\t\t" << h.e_machine << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Version:\t\t" << h.e_version << std::endl;
    std::cout << "entry:\t\t" << h.e_entry << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phoff:\t\t" << h.e_phoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shoff:\t\t" << h.e_shoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "flags:\t\t" << h.e_flags << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ehsize:\t\t" << h.e_ehsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phentsize:\t\t" << h.e_phentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phnum:\t\t" << h.e_phnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shentsize:\t\t" << h.e_shentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shnum:\t\t" << h.e_shnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shstrndx:\t\t" << h.e_shstrndx << std::endl;
}

void PrintPHStr()
{
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\tProgram header" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "type\t"
              << "offset\t"
              << "vaddr\t"
              << "paddr\t"
              << "filesz\t"
              << "memsz\t"
              << "flags\t"
              << "align\t" << std::endl;
}
void PrintSMTab()
{
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\tSymbol Table" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
}

void PrintRETab()
{
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\tRelocation Table" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
}
void PrintSHStr()
{
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\tSection header" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "name\t\t\t"
              << "type\t"
              << "flags\t"
              << "addr\t"
              << "offset\t"
              << "size\t"
              << "link\t"
              << "info\t"
              << "addralign\t"
              << "entsize\t" << std::endl;
}

void PrintPHVec32(std::vector<Elf32_Phdr> &PHs32)
{
    PrintPHStr();
    for (auto &e : PHs32)
    {
        std::cout << e.p_type << "\t" << e.p_offset << "\t" << e.p_vaddr << "\t" << e.p_paddr << "\t" << e.p_filesz << "\t" << e.p_memsz << "\t" << e.p_flags << "\t" << e.p_align << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
}
void PrintPHVec64(std::vector<Elf64_Phdr> &PHs64)
{
    PrintPHStr();

    for (auto &e : PHs64)
    {
        std::cout << e.p_type << "\t" << e.p_offset << "\t" << e.p_vaddr << "\t" << e.p_paddr << "\t" << e.p_filesz << "\t" << e.p_memsz << "\t" << e.p_flags << "\t" << e.p_align << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <elf.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern uint8_t *g_stager;
extern uint8_t *g_stager_end;

void addSection(std::string &sectionName, std::string &section, std::vector<unsigned char> &buffer)
{

    if (buffer[4] == 1) // if elf is 32 bit
    {

    }
    else
    {
        Elf64_Ehdr header;
        uint32_t offset = 0;
        uint64_t SectionSize = section.length() + 1;
        uint32_t sh_name = 0;
        uint32_t target = 0;
        uint8_t *stager_buf = nullptr;
        uint32_t stager_size = 0;
        uint32_t symTabOffset = 0;
        uint32_t symNum = 0;
        uint32_t symTabSec = 0;
        uint32_t strTabSec = 0;
        uint32_t mySymOffset = 0;
        uint32_t lastSymStrOffset = 0;
        uint32_t lastSymStrSec = 0;
        uint32_t relaIndex = 0;
        uint32_t mainOffset = 0;
        std::string secName;
        std::string strTaOffset;
        std::string symbolStr = "_mySymbol";
        symbolStr.push_back('\0');
        std::cout << "symbolStr.length() " << symbolStr.length() << std::endl;
        secName.reserve(100);

        stager_size = (uintptr_t)&g_stager_end - (uintptr_t)&g_stager;
        stager_buf = (uint8_t *)malloc(stager_size);
        memcpy(stager_buf, &g_stager, stager_size);

        SectionSize += stager_size;

        uint32_t PHTarget = 0;
        memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));

        std::cout << "header.e_entry " << header.e_entry << std::endl;
        *(uint32_t *)(stager_buf + 2) = header.e_entry;

        std::vector<Elf64_Phdr> PHs64(header.e_phnum);

        offset = header.e_phoff;

        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_phnum; i++)
        {
            memcpy(&PHs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_phentsize);
            offset += header.e_phentsize;

            if (PHs64[i].p_flags == 5)
            {
                PHTarget = i;
            }
        }

        PHs64[PHTarget].p_filesz += SectionSize;
        PHs64[PHTarget].p_memsz += SectionSize;

        for (uint32_t i = PHTarget + 1; i < PHs64.size(); i++)
        {
            if (PHs64[i].p_offset > PHs64[PHTarget].p_offset)
            {
                PHs64[i].p_offset += SectionSize;
                PHs64[i].p_vaddr += SectionSize;
            }
        }

        offset = header.e_phoff;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < PHs64.size(); i++)
        {
            memcpy(buffer.data() + offset, &PHs64[i], header.e_phentsize);
            offset += header.e_phentsize;
        }

        std::vector<Elf64_Shdr> SHs64(header.e_shnum);

        offset = header.e_shoff;

        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_shnum; i++)
        {
            memcpy(&SHs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_shentsize);
            offset += header.e_shentsize;
            if (SHs64[i].sh_flags == 6 && SHs64[i].sh_offset >= PHs64[PHTarget].p_offset)
            {
                target = i;
            }
        }

        offset = SHs64[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < SHs64.size(); i++)
        {
            secName.clear();

            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                if (buffer[offset + SHs64[i].sh_name + j] != '\0')
                {
                    secName.push_back(buffer[offset + SHs64[i].sh_name + j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (secName == ".symtab")
            {
                symTabSec = i;
            }
            if (secName == ".strtab")
            {
                strTabSec = i;
            }
        }

        offset = SHs64[symTabSec].sh_offset;

        symNum = SHs64[symTabSec].sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym);
        std::vector<Elf64_Sym> SMs64(symNum);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < symNum; i++)
        {
            memcpy(&SMs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, sizeof(Elf64_Sym));
            offset += sizeof(Elf64_Sym);
            if (SMs64[i].st_name > lastSymStrOffset)
            {
                lastSymStrOffset = SMs64[i].st_name;
                lastSymStrSec = i;
            }
        }

        offset = SHs64[strTabSec].sh_offset;
        for (auto &e : SMs64)
        {
            secName.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (buffer[offset + e.st_name + i] != '\0')
                {
                    secName.push_back(buffer[offset + e.st_name + i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (secName == "main")
            {
                mainOffset = e.st_value;
                std::cout << "main offset " << mainOffset << std::endl;
            }
        }
        // *(uint32_t *)(stager_buf + 2) = mainOffset;

        offset = SHs64[strTabSec].sh_offset + lastSymStrOffset;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[offset + i] != '\0')
            {
                std::cout << buffer[offset + i];
                lastSymStrOffset++;
            }
            else
            {
                lastSymStrOffset++;
                break;
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
        offset = SHs64[strTabSec].sh_offset + lastSymStrOffset;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < symbolStr.length(); i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, symbolStr[i]);
        }

        SHs64[strTabSec].sh_size += symbolStr.length();

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < SHs64.size(); i++)
        {
            if (SHs64[i].sh_offset > SHs64[strTabSec].sh_offset)
            {
                SHs64[i].sh_offset += symbolStr.length();
            }

            if (SHs64[i].sh_type == 4)
            {

                if (SHs64[i].sh_flags == 0x4)
                {
                    relaIndex = i;
                }

            }
        }

        Elf64_Sym smt;
        smt.st_name = lastSymStrOffset;
        smt.st_info = 18;
        smt.st_other = 0;
        smt.st_shndx = target + 1;
        smt.st_size = 0;
        smt.st_value = SHs64[target].sh_offset + SHs64[target].sh_size;

        char symStr[sizeof(Elf64_Sym)];
        memcpy(&symStr, &smt, sizeof(Elf64_Sym));

        std::cout << "target " << std::dec << target << std::endl;
        offset = SHs64[target].sh_offset + SHs64[target].sh_size;

        for (auto &e : SMs64)
        {
            if (e.st_shndx > target && e.st_shndx != SHN_ABS && e.st_shndx != SHN_COMMON)
            {
                e.st_shndx++;
            }
        }

        offset = SHs64[symTabSec].sh_offset;
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < SMs64.size(); i++)
        {
            if (SMs64[i].st_value > smt.st_value)
            {
                SMs64[i].st_value += SectionSize;
            }
            memcpy(buffer.data() + offset, &SMs64[i], sizeof(Elf64_Sym));
            offset += sizeof(Elf64_Sym);
        }

        offset = SHs64[target].sh_offset + SHs64[target].sh_size;
        *(uint32_t *)(stager_buf + 6) = offset;

        std::cout << "Old entry point: " << std::hex << header.e_entry << std::endl;
        std::cout << "New entry point: " << std::hex << offset << std::endl;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < stager_size; i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, stager_buf[i]);
        }

        offset += stager_size;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < section.length(); i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, section[i]);
        }

        offset += section.length();

        buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset, '\0');

        header.e_shoff += SectionSize + sizeof(Elf64_Sym) + symbolStr.length();
        // header.e_shoff += SectionSize + sizeof(Elf64_Sym) + symbolStr.length() + sizeof(Elf64_Rela);

        Elf64_Shdr sec;
        sec.sh_size = SectionSize;
        sec.sh_type = 1;
        sec.sh_flags = 6;
        sec.sh_name = SHs64[target].sh_name + sectionName.length();
        sec.sh_offset = SHs64[target].sh_offset + SHs64[target].sh_size;
        sec.sh_addr = sec.sh_offset;
        sec.sh_addralign = 0x10;
        sec.sh_link = 0;
        sec.sh_info = 0;
        sec.sh_entsize = 0;

        uint32_t targetSh_name = SHs64[target].sh_name;
        uint32_t entry = sec.sh_offset;

        for (uint32_t i = target + 1; i < SHs64.size(); i++)
        {
            if (SHs64[i].sh_offset > sec.sh_offset)
            {
                SHs64[i].sh_offset += SectionSize;
            }

            if (SHs64[i].sh_addr > sec.sh_addr)
            {
                SHs64[i].sh_addr += SectionSize;
            }

            if (SHs64[i].sh_name > targetSh_name)
            {
                SHs64[i].sh_name += sectionName.length() + 1;
            }
        }
        ///////////////////// insert symbol ////////////////////

        offset = SHs64[symTabSec].sh_offset + SHs64[symTabSec].sh_size;
        std::cout << std::hex << "SHs64[symTabSec].sh_offset " << offset << std::endl;
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Elf64_Sym); i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, symStr[i]);
        }
        SHs64[symTabSec].sh_size += sizeof(Elf64_Sym);
        SHs64[symTabSec].sh_link++;
        for (uint32_t i = symTabSec + 1; i < SHs64.size(); i++)
        {
            SHs64[i].sh_offset += sizeof(Elf64_Sym);
        }

        SHs64[SHs64.size() - 1].sh_size += sectionName.length() + 1;
        offset = header.e_shoff;
        std::cout << "+++++++++++++++ " << offset << "+++++++++++++++++" << std::endl;
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < SHs64.size(); i++)
        {
            memcpy(buffer.data() + offset, &SHs64[i], header.e_shentsize);
            offset += header.e_shentsize;
        }

        offset = header.e_shoff + (header.e_shentsize * (target + 1));

        char str[header.e_shentsize];
        memcpy(&str, &sec, header.e_shentsize);

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < header.e_shentsize; i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, str[i]);
        }
        header.e_shnum++;
        header.e_shstrndx++;

        offset = SHs64[SHs64.size() - 1].sh_offset;
        offset += targetSh_name + sectionName.length();

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sectionName.length(); i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, sectionName[i]);
        }

        offset += sectionName.length();
        buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset, '\0');

        header.e_shoff += sectionName.length() + 1;

        header.e_entry = entry;

        memcpy(buffer.data(), &header, sizeof(header));

        std::ofstream fout("Test_bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        chmod("Test_bin", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);

        std::copy(buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(fout));

        free(stager_buf);

        fout.close();
    }
}
```

```
.global g_stager
.global g_stager_end

g_stager:
    .incbin "stager.bin"
g_stager_end:
```

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

base:
    jmp past

e_entry:
.long 0

patch_ofs:
.long 0

past:
    push rdi                   /* Preserve registers */
    push rsi                   /*   ... */
    push rdx                   /*   ... */
    call payload               /* Call the payload */
    mov eax, [rip + e_entry]   /* Get offset of real entry  */
    mov ebx, [rip + patch_ofs] /* Get offset of the stager */
    sub rbx, rax               /* Compute the delta between the stager and the real entry offsets */
    lea r10, [rip + base]      /* Get vaddr of the stager */
    sub r10, rbx               /* Subtract the delta from vaddr of the stager to get the vaddr of real entry */
    pop rdx                    /* Restore registers */
    pop rsi                    /*   ... */
    pop rdi                    /*   ... */
    jmp r10                    /* Jump to real entry */

payload:
/* Payload blob is appended to the end of this blob */
```

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

jmp past

message:
    .ascii "See, I am drow, and I'd like to say hello,\n"
    .ascii "To the black, to the white, the red and the brown,\n"
    .ascii "The purple and yellow. But first, I gotta\n"
    .ascii "Bang bang, the boogie to the boogie,\n"
    .ascii "Say up jump the boogie to the bang bang boogie,\n"
    .ascii "Let's rock, you don't stop ...\n\n"

past:
    mov rdi, 1                    /* STDOUT file descriptor */
    lea rsi, [rip + message]      /* Pointer to message string */
    mov rdx, 253                  /* Message size */
    mov rax, 1                    /* Write syscall number */
    syscall                       /* Execute system call */
    ret                           /* Return back to caller */
```

In my opinion, the problem is probably from the linker
I added an entry for realocation table and GOT.
But the problem was not solved.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: Are you asking us how to write a virus?! ;)